# How can I efficiently convert the output voltage of a 3 phase generator of 700V to 12V, 24V or 48V DC?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, generator, windturbine

I recently bought a wind turbine electric brushless generator rated for 3kW. I noticed that the output voltage is really high - it is around 700V at 5400 RPM. After some research on stackexchange, I found out that using a 3 phase rectifier with a DC-DC flyback is one efficient way to achieve my goal.

- Is there any better solution?
- Would this setup guarantee a stable output voltage with variable current or is it more common for such a wind turbine to attach 3 transformers to each phase and convert it directly to 230V AC?

[image]

Comment: It depends on the load current.

Comment: How fast will your wind turbine be driving it?

Comment: Please clarify what your intention is. In the title of your question you mention conversion to low-voltage DC, but in these comments you are now thinking about grid-tie inversion (which will involve a high-voltage DC stage followed by a separate grid-tied inverter). If you don't make a decision this question may get closed for being too vague.

Comment: Wind is variable

Comment: Transformer down to 230 Vac and use a commercial off the shelf AC/DC converter.

Comment: but i want a stable output voltage

Comment: Do you need only one output that will be 12. 24 or 48 VDC or do you need multiple voltages? Will you design everything or are you hoping to purchase some packaged converters? What will be the minimum and maximum speed? Do you have a good wind turbine curve and wind-speed forecast? Do you want maximum efficiency regardless of cost? How will you determine the wind speed and electrical load at which maximum efficiency is desired?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks detail and clarity. Some details in the comments are not in the question. With complete details, the question may be too broad to answer here.

Comment: You can not convert variable 3-phase AC directly to 230 V AC with just a 3-phase transformer, but a transformer may be part of the best solution.

Comment: Dont tell me there are so many solutions and the question is too broad to answer when you cant even give 1 solution. Thinking knowing everything and trying to fit on each question topic is really a bad attitude. 700 v 3 phase ac to 12v dc. Somebody who doesnt understand this question should simply be man enough to say i cannot help on this topic instead of asking about birds and trees when i am asking about a soup recipe.

Comment: You may be asking for a soup recipe, but the problem at hand doesn't look cooking a soup. You didn't ask about *700 V 3 phase AC to low voltage DC*, but *generator output to low voltage DC*. (700 V * 26 A - about 18kVA would be a lot for 3 kW generator/windmill as well as 5400 RPM - and at lower speed, you aren't looking at 700 V.)

Comment: Please search on google for soup recipes if your are hungry. I know what I asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any solution better than a 3 phase rectifier with a DC-DC flyback?

As [Andy aka commented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520522/3-phase-generator#comment1337440_520522), this depends on the load.
In the kW range, a forward converter looks more attractive.

For a none-too-wide range of voltages, an off-the-shelf power supply or battery charger looks an attractive option.
If not specified for operation from DC as well as from AC, contact vendor - I don't imagine there is a problem running off a 6 pulse rectifier with pulses 10 ms apart at most.
Alternatives to a transformer to get into the component's range of input voltage include a mechanical gear at the generator's input - 5400 RPM is a lot, even 1774 for 230 V.

Comment: (OTOH, I get 5/7 of rated stall torque at 5400 RPM for 3 kW.)